# Vagrant localhost 8080 connection issue

Tags: python-3.x, vagrant, virtualbox

I am new to vagrant using Windows 10. Started a course on Udacity(Full stack foundation). Now i have created a simple web server script but when i am testing it on localhost:8080 showing error : site can't be reached. Tried a lot but unable to find the solution. On **netstat -aon** showing 0.0.0.0:8080 listening on pid no 1072 but pid is not there in running servies (using Clt+Alt+Del).

**web server script** - webserver.py

```
from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
class WebServerHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path.endswith("/hello"):
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
            self.end_headers()
            message = ""
            message += "<html><body>Hello!</body></html>"
            self.wfile.write(message)
            print message
            return
        if self.path.endswith("/hola"):
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
            self.end_headers()
            message = ""
            message += "<html><body>Hola!</body></html>"
            self.wfile.write(message)
            print message
            return
        else:
            self.send_error(404, 'File Not Found: %s' % self.path)
def main():
    try:
        port = 8080
        server = HTTPServer(('', port), WebServerHandler)
        print "Web Server running on port %s" % port
        server.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print " ^C entered, stopping web server...."
        server.socket.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Code is executing and terminating properly with no error but on testing it on http://localhost:8080/hello (site can't be reached).

Help me. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Depends on how you are forwarding your ports

Comment: Maybe you find this [guide](https://github.com/Varying-Vagrant-Vagrants/VVV/wiki/Connect-to-Your-Vagrant-Virtual-Machine-with-PuTTY) useful

Comment: So what  should i do now to run on localhost:8080?

Comment: In my Vagrantfile "config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080" and private_network is not commented. i have removed the comment.

Comment: Try to access the link with curl from the VM. Something like: `curl http://localhost:8080/hello`

Comment: vagrant ssh-config is showing that port is 2222 and ip is 127.0.0.1

Comment: Did you try accessing the url with curl from VM?

Comment: i am sorry i am new i don't know how to do this.

Comment: The same way you ran netstat, you can run in command line: `curl http://localhost:8080/hello`

Comment: Yes it is printing <html><body>Hello!</body></html> which is my message.

Comment: Then either port 8080 is not forwarded, or maybe it's blocked by vagrant VM firewall. I think by default port 8080 is forwarded to port 80 or 8000. You can try your luck by accessing it in browser : `http://localhost/hello` or `http://localhost:8000/hello`

Comment: You can open port 8080 using `ufw`. Another command line app. Google it for more information. If that is all you can mark this question as answered :). I will post the answer soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to access the link with curl from the VM: `curl http://localhost:8080/hello`.

If the response is OK, it means either port 8080 is not forwarded, or maybe it's blocked by vagrant VM firewall. You can open your port for testing purpose using `ufw`.

Comment: Tried ufw. allowed 8080 status is also showing 8080 is allowed but still on executing script localhost:8080/hello showing "this site can't be reached".

Comment: If you want to access it on localhost i think you must forward port 8080. If you want to access it from outside, you should access the VM ip. (ifconfig to find your VM ip, then access it : `http://{ip_here}:8080/hello`

Comment: Please read this [documentation](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/forwarded_ports.html) on how to forward your ports. Also note that after you forward some ports, you need to reload your vagrant (`vagrant reload`)

Comment: In your vagrantfile: `config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8080, host: 8080, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"`. Then reload vagrant

Comment: hey this **http://{ip_here}:8080/hello** worked for me. Thanks a ton dear. grateful to you @Xing

Comment: I'm glad you succeeded. When you have time you should also try forwarding your ports in vagrant file (see comments above) as a more elegant solution

Comment: yes i will try instead i should say that i have tried that solution too but may be because of little knowledge it didn't solve my problem. But **yes** i'll try again. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I changed the host and port in the **Python App** from this:

```py
run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)
```

to this:

```py
run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5002, debug=True)
```

---

and in the **vagrantfile** from this:

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8080, host: 8080, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"
```

to this:

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 5002, host: 5002
```

then test a request and **do NOT forget to add the resource (URL endpoint)** 'hello' in my example: `http://0.0.0.0:5002/hello`

this fixed the issue for me.